# Tables from panda is not properly formatted

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to convert a dictionary item into tables using pandas, but the problem is that I am not getting the desired results.
here is my code below

```
value = new_stock(data)


dict_stocks = {i: value[i] for i in range (0, len(value))}

df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_stocks.items()), columns =['Company Name', 'Price per share', Total valuation])

print(df)
```

I want the output to be like

```
Company name                           price per share       Total valuation
Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd.', '16.41 Dollars', '3498661376 billion dollars'
Carnival Corporation & Plc', '15.5 Dollars', '10927298560 billion dollars'
```

But my output is in this format.

```
Company Name                                    Price per share
0              0  (Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd., 16.41 Do...
1              1  (Carnival Corporation & Plc, 15.5 Dollars, 109...
2              2  (Noble Energy, Inc., 10.05 Dollars, 4874652160...
3              3  (Apache Corporation, 13.05 Dollars, 4925304832...
4              4  (Companhia Siderurgica Nacional, 1.66 Dollars,...
5              5  (DCP Midstream, LP, 10.03 Dollars, 2089549824 ...
6              6  (Sabre Corporation, 7.4 Dollars, 2025794432 bi...
7              7  (Sasol Limited, 5.13 Dollars, 3016778496 billi...
8              8  (Continental Resources, Inc., 15.85 Dollars, 5...
9              9  (Marathon Oil Corporation, 5.85 Dollars, 46239...
10            10  (AerCap Holdings N.V., 28.47 Dollars, 37461678...
11            11  (Penn National Gaming, Inc., 18.61 Dollars, 21...
12            12  (Royal Caribbean Cruises Ltd., 48.06 Dollars, ...
13            13  (Canadian Natural Resources Limited, 17.38 Dol...
14            14  (WPX Energy, Inc., 6.08 Dollars, 3400939008 bi...
15            15  (Ryman Hospitality Properties, Inc., 37.78 Dol...
16            16  (TechnipFMC plc, 9.27 Dollars, 4124464384 bill...
17            17  (Diamondback Energy, Inc., 44.19 Dollars, 6973...
18            18  (Santander Consumer USA Holdings Inc., 17.05 D...
19            19  (Marathon Petroleum Corporation, 33.04 Dollars...
20            20  (Air Lease Corporation, 26.72 Dollars, 3036327...
21            21  (Carnival Corporation & Plc, 16.69 Dollars, 13...
22            22  (Howmet Aerospace Inc., 13.89 Dollars, 6054915...
23            23  (Aaron's, Inc., 32.33 Dollars, 2184589824 bill...
24            24  (Tata Motors Limited, 5.88 Dollars, 3851547136...
```

I would appreciate any Help given

****** additional****
Here is the remaining part of the code

```
import requests
import pprint
import json
import pandas as pd


url = "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/ga/topgainers"

querystring = {"start":"0"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "9efd0f3e52mshd859f5daf34a429p11cb2ajsn2b0e421d681e"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = response.json()

#print(response.text)


def new_stock(data):
    new_market = []

    for item in data ['quotes']:
        new_name = item.get ('longName')
        new_price = item.get ('regularMarketPrice')
        res_price = (f'{new_price} Dollars')
        cap =item.get('marketCap')
        if cap >= 1000000000:
            cap = f'{cap} billion dollars'
        else:
            cap = f'{cap} million dollars'
        new_market.append((new_name, res_price, cap))

    return new_market

value = new_stock(data)
```

Comment: can you share a subset of the variable value?

Comment: Please share your `dictionary`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal updated

Comment: @datanovice updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
In [403]: value = [('Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd.', 
     ...:   '16.41 Dollars', 
     ...:   '3498661376 billion dollars'), 
     ...:  ('Carnival Corporation & Plc', '15.5 Dollars', '10927298560 billion dollars'), 
     ...:  ('Noble Energy, Inc.', '10.05 Dollars', '4874652160 billion dollars'), 
     ...:  ('Apache Corporation', '13.05 Dollars', '4925304832 billion dollars'), 
     ...:  ('Companhia Siderurgica Nacional', 
     ...:   '1.66 Dollars', 
     ...:   '1905845888 billion dollars'), 
     ...:  ('DCP Midstream, LP', '10.03 Dollars', '2089549824 billion dollars')]

In [407]: df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=['Company name','price per share','Total valuation'])                                                                                                            

In [408]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[408]: 
                          Company name price per share              Total valuation
0  Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd.   16.41 Dollars   3498661376 billion dollars
1           Carnival Corporation & Plc    15.5 Dollars  10927298560 billion dollars
2                   Noble Energy, Inc.   10.05 Dollars   4874652160 billion dollars
3                   Apache Corporation   13.05 Dollars   4925304832 billion dollars
4       Companhia Siderurgica Nacional    1.66 Dollars   1905845888 billion dollars
5                    DCP Midstream, LP   10.03 Dollars   2089549824 billion dollars
```